# XSLT remove duplicate children

Tags: xslt, duplicates, element, children

I am looking for an XSLT transformation to de-duplicate the children element of a parent.
In my case both parent and children are given (i.e I don't want to deduplicate any children of any element).

for example, say I want to deduplicate the `<ID>` children of `<ROWSET>`

input:

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
         <ID> 1 </ID>
         ...
         <ID> 1 </ID>
         ...
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
         <ID> 2 </ID>
         ...
         <ID> 2 </ID>
         ...
    </ROW>
    ...
</ROWSET>
```

I want the output to be

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
         <ID> 1 </ID>
         ...
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
         <ID> 2 </ID>
         ...
    </ROW>
    ...
</ROWSET>
```

where '...' indicates the presence of any number of any other tags.

edit:
there may be anything between the two duplicate children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and straightforward approach to ignore id which have am id with same content as previous element for same parent.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match ="ID" >
        <xsl:if test="not (preceding-sibling::ID/text() = current()/text())" >
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This should work anyway, if - as I understood that the duplicated  elements are belonging to the same parent.

Answer (score 2):

You have a solution, but it might be more efficient to use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="equal" match="ROW/ID" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', .)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW/ID[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('equal', concat(generate-id(..), '|', .))[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```