# XSLT removing arbitrary duplicate sibling elements

Tags: xslt

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715399/288341) is doing exactly what I want except that I don't want to just remove duplicate siblings of a specific element, I want to remove duplicate siblings of all elements.

Additionally, for my purposes a "duplicate" element will have the same attributes, descendant elements, and text as its sibling.

How can that answer be modified to achieve my goal?

Here is my current style sheet:

**XSL:**

```
<!--
    When a file is transformed using this stylesheet the output will be
    formatted as follows:

    1.)  Elements named "info" will be removed
    2.)  Duplicate sibling elements will be removed
    3.)  Attributes named "file_line_nr" or "file_name" will be removed
    4.)  Comments will be removed
    5.)  Processing instructions will be removed
    6.)  XML declaration will be removed
    7.)  Extra whitespace will be removed
    8.)  Empty attributes will be removed
    9.)  Elements which have no attributes, child elements, or text will be removed
    10.) All elements will be sorted by name recursively
    11.) All attributes will be sorted by name
-->
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--
        Elements/attributes to remove.  Note that comments are not elements or
        attributes.  Since there is no template to match comments they are
        automatically ignored.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@*[normalize-space()='']|info|@file_line_nr|@file_name"/>

    <!-- Match any attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match any element -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="elementFragment">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
                    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="element" select="xalan:nodeset($elementFragment)/*"/>
        <xsl:if test="$element/@* or $element/* or normalize-space($element)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$element"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!-- XML declaration should be removed -->
<z b="b" a="a" c="c">
    <?some-app inst="some instruction"?><!-- Processing instructions should be removed -->
    <a><!-- Keep elements like this because it has child elements -->
        <x c="c" b="b" a="a"/><!-- Keep elements like this because it has attributes -->
        <c>some text</c><!-- Keep elements like this because it has text -->
        <info a="a"/><!-- Elements named "info" are to be removed -->
        <w file_line_nr="42" file_name="somefile.txt"/><!-- Attributes named "file_line_nr" and "file_name" are to be removed which will leave this element empty, so it should be removed too -->
        <d/><!-- Remove elements like this because it has not attributes, no children, and no text -->

        <v a="a"><!-- Keep this element because it and it sibling "v" element are unique.. It does not have the same exact descendants as its sibling "v" element -->
            some text
            <i a="a">some text</i>
            <q a="a">some text</q>
        </v>
        <v a="a">
            some text
            <i a="a">some different text</i><!-- text is different -->
            <q a="a">some text</q>
        </v>

        <e a="a"><!-- Keep this element because it and it sibling "e" element are unique.. It does not have the same exact descendants as its sibling "e" element -->
            some text
            <j a="a">
                <p>some text</p>
            </j>
        </e>
        <e a="a">
            some text
            <j a="a">
                <p>some different text</p><!-- text is different -->
            </j>
        </e>

        <u a="a"><!-- Keep this element because it and it sibling "e" element are unique.. It does not have the same exact descendants as its sibling "e" element -->
            some text
            <k a="a">some text</k>
            <n a="a">some text</n>
        </u>
        <u a="a">
            some text
            <k b="b">some text</k><!-- attribute is different -->
            <n a="a">some text</n>
        </u>

        <f a="a"><!-- Keep this element because it and it sibling "f" element are unique.. It does not have the same exact attributes as its sibling "f" element -->
            some text
            <l a="a">some text</l>
            <m a="a">some text</m>
        </f>
        <f b="b"><!-- attribute is different -->
            some text
            <l a="a">some text</l>
            <m a="a">some text</m>
        </f>

        <t a="a"><!-- Keep this element because it and it sibling "t" element are unique. It does not have the same exact text as its sibling "t" element -->
            some text
            <az a="a">some text</az>
            <aa a="a">some text</aa>
        </t>
        <t a="a">
            some different text<!-- text is different -->
            <az a="a">some text</az>
            <aa a="a">some text</aa>
        </t>

        <g a="a"><!-- Remove this element because it is NOT unique. Its attributes, descendants, and text are exactly the same as its sibling "g" element -->
            some text
            <ay a="a">some text</ay>
            <ab a="a">some text</ab>
        </g>
        <g a="a">
            some text
            <ay a="a">some text</ay>
            <ab a="a">some text</ab>
        </g>

        <s a="a"/>
    </a>
    <y a="a"/>
    <b>
        <h a="a" />
        <r a="a"/>
    </b>
</z>
```

**Desired Output XML:** (Elements and attributes sorted.  Comments and indentation/whitespace would also be removed, but I have added them back in here for readability.)

```
<z a="a" b="b" c="c">
    <a>
        <c>some text</c>
        <e a="a">
            some text
            <j a="a">
                <p>some text</p>
            </j>
        </e>
        <e a="a">
            some text
            <j a="a">
                <p>some different text</p>
            </j>
        </e>
        <f a="a">
            some text
            <l a="a">some text</l>
            <m a="a">some text</m>
        </f>
        <f b="b">
            some text
            <l a="a">some text</l>
            <m a="a">some text</m>
        </f>
        <g a="a"><!-- The sibling "g" element of this element was removed because it was an exact duplicate -->
            some text
            <ab a="a">some text</ab>
            <ay a="a">some text</ay>
        </g>
        <s a="a"/>
        <t a="a">
            some text
            <aa a="a">some text</aa>
            <az a="a">some text</az>
        </t>
        <t a="a">
            some different text
            <aa a="a">some text</aa>
            <az a="a">some text</az>
        </t>
        <u a="a">
            some text
            <k a="a">some text</k>
            <n a="a">some text</n>
        </u>
        <u a="a">
            some text
            <k b="b">some text</k>
            <n a="a">some text</n>
        </u>
        <v a="a">
            some text
            <i a="a">some text</i>
            <q a="a">some text</q>
        </v>
        <v a="a">
            some text
            <i a="a">some different text</i>
            <q a="a">some text</q>
        </v>
        <x a="a" b="b" c="c"/>
    </a>
    <b>
        <h a="a"/>
        <r a="a"/>
    </b>
    <y a="a"/>
</z>
```

Comment: An example of your input XML would be nice for testing purposes.

Comment: @BenL Updated question with example input XML and desired output XML.

Comment: Can't you use Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 with its `deep-equal` function instead of Xalan and XSLT 1.0 extensions?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'll give it a try, but using Saxon-HE I lose the ability to specify `indent-amount` as you can see by my comment to your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18771079/288341) and my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18772415/288341).  I can live without the indent feature if I have to because I have to find some way to remove duplicate siblings even if I am unable to use XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have been reading a bit on `deep-equal` but with my limited understanding of XSLT I'm unclear where it will fit into my current stylesheet.  I have been trying to fit it into my `Elements/attributes to remove` template with little luck.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I got a new error that reads ***Saxon extension functions are not available under Saxon-HE***.  Since `deep-equal` is an extension function I guess my company will have to buy a license if this is to work.

Comment: No, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal is part of XPath 2.0 and not an extension function and is supported in all versions of Saxon 9.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Ok, I was looking at [this](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/deepequal.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion to show how `deep-equal` and XSLT 2.0 could help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity for most attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except (processing-instruction(), comment())" group-adjacent="boolean(self::*)">
             <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                   <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
                 </xsl:apply-templates>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
               </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        Elements/attributes to remove.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@*[normalize-space()='']|info|@file_line_nr|@file_name
                         | *[not(@* | node())]"/>


    <!-- remove (well, don't copy) element nodes which are deep-equal to
         a preceding sibling element 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="*[some $ps in preceding-sibling::* satisfies deep-equal(., $ps)]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want, but an element's duplicate could have been ANY previous sibling, not just the "preceding-sibling".  I tried just using `preceding`, but that didn't work.

Comment: You could change `<xsl:template match="*[deep-equal(., preceding-sibling::*[1])]"/>` to `<xsl:template match="*[some $ps in preceding-sibling::* satisfies deep-equal(., $ps)]"/>`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Thank you for also fixing my warning with `<xsl:copy>` too. A few other things I noticed: ***1.)*** You moved the "remove" template to the bottom. Does the order of these templates matter? ***2.)*** You changed the comment on the same template you fixed the warning on. The comment now reads "identity for most elements and attributes". My XSL nomenclature is not good, why your comment more accurate?  I thought that template only matched attributes, is that not true?

Comment: Sorry about the `<!-- identity for most elements and attributes -->` comment, it is wrong with the version of code I posted, I think I originally had no sorting of child elements and a single template matching `@* | *`. I will edit the code to fix the comment. As for the order of templates, yes it matters if there are two templates matching the same node, in that case the processor can report an error or choose the last template. I have not checked in detail however if the problem occurs with the posted code, Saxon emits a warning if that happens so check with your samples whether you get one.

Comment: My jubilation was premature. All of my small test files transformed just fine, but when I run it on one of the big files I'm actually concerned about a lot of data gets consumed.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/aqKBspME) is a section of an XML file I'm having trouble with (please forgive the obfuscation), and [here](http://pastebin.com/LMCjSrEM) is the expected output.  For some reason the actual output isn't even close to the expected output using the stylesheet from your answer.

Comment: @ubiquibacon, I had to correct one match pattern, I think you should now get what you want.

Comment: Awesome.  I see now that I have one other problem though.  When `deep-equal` is called it is being called on the original sequence which still has the elements/attributes in it that I want to be removed.  Those elements/attributes are causing "differences" in `deep-equal`.  See my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830250/how-to-remove-elements-attributes-from-sequence-before-deep-equal-is-applied).